# Discord bot to play an mp3 only works for previous joined users

Tags: python, discord.py

i have a small project for a handicapped friend, where a Discord bot would play an .mp3 on a user joining a voice channel. So far, so good. But it only works for users who have joined the channel before the bot did. Any user joining afterwards wouldn't hear the bot's "Voice".

Bot joining:

```
if voice_client:
    await voice_client.disconnect()
try:
    channel = message.author.voice.channel
except AttributeError:
    await message.channel.send('!User is not in accessible voice channel!')
voice_client = await channel.connect(reconnect=False)
```

Playing the .mp3:

```
if voice_client:
    audio_source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe('motd.mp3')
    voice_client.play(audio_source)
    while voice_client.is_playing():
        continue
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is checking out discord.py's official Music example. They show you how to correctly play music and its pretty good code. But what you can also do for the play command is, `voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("audio.mp3")`
Feel free to reply here or reach out to me on discord (koyashie#0001) if you need any help finishing the bot!